Spring integration assert that message has been sent to particular channel
I've a spring-boot event based project using spring-integration library.
The whole flow can be desribed as

A single event received from kafka is processed by a single thread end to end and as such all my channels are DirectChannel
I want to write integration test case for one of the validation failures; Where in one of my assertions will be that the message has been sent to DiscardChannel
How do i do this ?
Possible approaches I could think of :

Create a dummy subscriber to DiscardChannel in tests and assert on the received message.

    @TestConfiguration
    public class SampleTestConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "discardChannel")
    public MessageChannel invalidDiscardChannel() {
        PublishSubscribeChannel publishSubscribeChannel = new PublishSubscribeChannel();
        publishSubscribeChannel.setComponentName("discardChannel");
        return publishSubscribeChannel;
    }
    }

    public class SampleIntegrationTest{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("discardChannel")
    MessageChannel discardChannel;

    @Test
    public void testInvalidMessage() {
        //initiate the flow


        List<Message<?>> messages = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        ((PublishSubscribeChannel)discardChannel).subscribe(messages::add);

        
        await().atMost(Durations.TEN_SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> {
            
            //other assertions
            assertTrue(messages.size() > 0);
            Message<?> message = messages.get(0);
            assertNotNull(message);
            
        });
    }    

Above approach forces me to define the channel as PublishSubscribeChannel in tests so that it can be subscribed twice

Create a ChannelInterceptor and assert on the intercepted message

 private static class PostCompleteAsserter implements  ChannelInterceptor{
            
        private final Runnable assertionLogic;

        public PostCompleteAsserter(Runnable assertionLogic) {
            this.assertionLogic = assertionLogic;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterReceiveCompletion(@Nullable Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, @Nullable Exception ex) {
                assertionLogic.run();
            }
    }


    public class SampleIntegrationTest{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("discardChannel")
    MessageChannel discardChannel;

    @Test
    public void testInvalidMessage() {
         //initiate the flow

        
         ChannelInterceptor asserter = new PostCompleteAsserter(()-> 
 assertNotNull(message));

        ((DirectChannel)discardChannel).addInterceptor(asserter);
              
    }

Feel free to suggest any other approach / best practices  as well

Yes, the ChannelInterceptor approach is OK if you expect that real subscriber to the channel will do it job. You probably indeed can just verify in that target subscriber that it has done the job for invalid message.
Another approach is to follow Integration Mock pattern and replace that real subscriber with something you can verify in the test.
See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/testing.html#test-context
